# Failed to isolate default target. Freezing execution. During Ubuntu 16.04 startup

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error 
Failed to execute default target. Freezing execution while starting up Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
How to solve this?

Comment: check the following link
https://askubuntu.com/questions/941252/ubuntu-doesnt-reboot

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462415/ .